# Background of Relative Layout is not filling all screen

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, screen

I have a problem when I use Relative Layout and a background. Although I set `android:layout_height="match_parent"`, the background is not filling all the screen (height of screen) and the bottom part is setting white. I am only putting items at the top part of the screen, but even so I don't believe that this behaviour is correct.

My code xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/background" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dim_b"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dim_a"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dim_a" />

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/insert"
    android:hint="@string/insert"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dim_c"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dim_a"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dim_a"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/accept"
    android:text="@string/accept"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/insert"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dim_d"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dim_a"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dim_a" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Remove all the child view in the RelativeLayout to have a try. I think  maybe there are some mistakes in the background drawable.

Answer (score 2):

> 1.First you are use Relative Layout so why you need orientation="verticlal" remove from top of the Relative layout
>
> 2.Edittext ,Button like this android:layout_below="@+id/title" not android:layout_below="@id/title"

Comment: I am agree with first, but not agree with second. For example, if I use android:layout_below="@id/insert" if because "insert" is the ID of first TextView, and it is already called with that ID. Thanks for your answer!!

Answer (score 0):

try:
android:layout_height="fill_parent"

match_parent is in API Level 8 and higher.

Comment: I am using min SDK version 8. Thanks!!